# How hard is it to use typo-dir.lua in LaTeX?

Tags: luatex, context, context-mkiv

I tried to use `typo-dir.lua` from ConTeXt distribution in LaTeX but I could not. I searched all context sources and I added all missing functions but still it did not work. Is it possible to use this Lua file in LaTeX? I am only trying to see how that works in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
require("typo-dir")
commands.setdirection(1)
}
\luatexpardir TRT
\luatextextdir TRT
\begin{document}
1984
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Using @phg's files, I get the following error:

```
./test-typo-dir.tex:4: LuaTeX error ...al/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context/ba
se/typo-dir.lua:48: attempt to index local 'mathcodes' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    ...al/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/typo-dir.lua:48: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ./import-typo-dir.lua:172: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ...xlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/modutils.lua:57: in function 're
quire_module'
    [string "\directlua "]:1: in main chunk.
\lltxb@requirelua ...xluaescapestring {#2}" \fi )}

l.4 

?
```

Comment: welcome back to the site

Answer (score 5):

## Short, correct answer

Don’t do this. Use Context instead.
The code is integrated too tightly into Context to be of practical use
outside of it.

(I know this is not a real answer to your question but it’s
nevertheless correct.)

## Longer, detailed answer

Since you ask how hard it would be: I consider it a medium to hard task
if you know what you are doing. Probably medium if you (unlike me) are
already familiar with the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm.
This gist: https://gist.github.com/phi-gamma/6488187 contains the
necessary Lua code as well as some example wrapper macros.
It requires the beta (unstable) version of Context (the version in Texlive 2013 is too old) which is most conveniently
acquired by installing the [Standalone distribution](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone).

In Context, Unicode bidi is implemented as a *node processor*, which is
a managed version of Luatex callbacks.
Normally, with some (in your case: extensive) preparation you can hook
any of these processors into the raw callback mechanism.
For an overview of what this entails you can refer to the steps taken
by Luaotfload in order to
[load Context’s letterspacing code](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/blob/master/luaotfload-extralibs.lua).

`typo-dir.lua` makes heavy use of Unicode character properties.
For its purposes, the character information provided by Luaotfload
does not suffice, so we have to load the entire character table
(`char-def.lua`).
Also, `char-ini.lua` is required because it installs a series of
special handlers that facilitate access to these properties.

**UPDATE** On 2013-09-09 the bidi code was split into `typo-dir.lua`
(node processor handling and interface), `typo-dha.lua` (main bidi node
processor), and `math-dir.lua` (math bidi).
The gist has been updated to reflect these changes.
Judging from the source and by the recent activity further changes can
be expected in the near future.

Besides those there are several further prerequisites:
we need to properly map Context’s interface to Luatex attributes onto
Luatexbase and preallocate three attributes that contain the bidi
state.
Also, the
[`context` namespace](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/cldf-ini.lua#l576)
must be present, so we set up a rudimentary substitute which supports
both the `__index` and the `__call` metamethods.
These are only the more complex requirements.
For orientation I annotated the source briefly.

I tested the result only against the demonstration section of
[`typo-dir.mkiv`](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/typo-dir.mkiv#l107).
Automatic switching of directions appears to work.
I cannot explain the differences in font rendering, though, but that’s
not what you asked `B-)`.
This is what it looks like -- Latex on the left, Context on the right
side:

[image: Comparison between Context and Latex output]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you use `typo-dir.lua` with LaTeX? If the answer is yes, could you please show me how to use it in LaTeX?

Comment: Have you read the gist I linked? The included ``.tex`` shows how.

Comment: Great, thanks. sorry I am almost getting old and my eyes sight gets weaker every day.

Comment: Oh, that’s sad to hear.
Hope the code will get you started.

Comment: Please see the edit in my question. When I run `lualatex`, I get error.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi Are you using the texlive version of Context? The directions code [got revised only two days ago](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/history/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/typo-dir.lua) and that is the version my wrapper targets. I’ll see if I can add more workarounds so it accepts the texlive version as well.

Comment: No problem, where should I download the new Context files? There is no need to modify it, I'll use the new version of context. Thanks

Comment: You can install the [Context Standalone](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone#Single_user_installation) distribution alongside texlive if you want the full system. Alternatively, if you just need those three files, get them [from the Context Garden server](http://standalone.contextgarden.net/current/context/beta/tex/context/base/) or the [third-party Git mirror](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/tree/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base).

Comment: I just got the three lua files and they indeed work very well. Thanks again.

Comment: I am the author of bidi package and I am writing another package (simurgh) for bidirectional typesetting in lualatex. The only thing that I yet can not do is unibidi and I was thinking of integrating `typo-dir.lua` in my package; would you like to be a co-author of simurgh and take care of the `typo-dir.lua`?

Comment: Thanks for the invitation. Unfortunately though I have to decline.
If you need more functionality (e.g. further information from ``char-def.lua``) to be integrated into Luaotfload, I’d be glad to assist.
Btw. Khaled Hosny has another [bidi implementation](https://bitbucket.org/khaledhosny/context-bidi) for Context that might be valuable for your goal. Also, there was some effort to integrate bidi functionality into Polyglossia a while ago, though I cannot say how much it progressed since.

Comment: For my purpose and my tests so far, `typo-dir.lua` does all I need. I have tried Khaled's bidi module too but it is not very robust. Arthur talked to me and he uploaded luabidi to CTAN (a package I wrote few years ago) but when I upload simurgh to CTAN, luabidi will be obsolete.

Comment: Just a heads up: today Hans [split ``typo-dir.lua``](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/commitdiff/44de30964e33453cd417a52f980eebf3fc1a0d31) into three files: you will now also need ``typo-dha.lua`` and ``math-dir.lua``. The transition turned out to be smooth so I have updated the gist accordingly.

Comment: @Vafa Khalighi Hans commented on the  different bidi implementations yesterday: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.context/84180 . The method in ``typo-dir.lua`` (now ``typo-dha.lua``) is the fast default one.

Comment: It doesn't work any longer. Do you have plans to update it? I'm working on the bidi support for babel and it could be useful, even if very likely I'll “reinvent the wheel”.

Comment: Well, I've found the original work by Khaled Hosny on https://github.com/khaledhosny/context-bidi . It works with a simple fix, namely, dir and local_par are now node types and not subtypes of whatsit.